# How to integrate okta-vue with VueCLI4

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli, okta, okta-api

I am attempting to set up a basic Vue authentication page using the Okta-Vue package. The tutorial I am referencing is here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/02/15/build-crud-app-vuejs-node. For this project, I am using VueCLI 4. After creating the project, I attempted to set up the Okta authentication protocols in the router file

index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import PostsManager from '@/components/PostsManager'
import OktaVue, { LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-vue'
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
  issuer: 'https://{dev-id}.okta.com/oauth2/default',
  clientId: '{clientId}',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/login/callback',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
})

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    component: LoginCallback
  },
  {
    path: '/posts-manager',
    name: 'PostsManager',
    component: PostsManager,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

The instructions for setting up this demo appear to be based on an older version of VueCLI, which expects `Vue` to be imported into the router file, in order to execute the following:

```
Vue.use(OktaVue, { oktaAuth })
```

Since Vue.use() is not part of the new version of the vue-router, what is the proper way to execute OktaVue and oktaAuth in the above router file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 3, the plugin is registered on the application instance from `createApp()` with [`app.use()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use), which is the equivalent to Vue 2's `Vue.use()`:

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter(⋯)
export default router
```

```js
// auth.js
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'

export const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(⋯)
```

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import OktaVue from '@okta/okta-vue'
import { oktaAuth } from './auth'

createApp(App)
  .use(OktaVue, { oktaAuth }) 
  .use(router)
  .mount('#app')
```